# gas water heater howls when gas is on

Tags: water, gas, heater

I had to move my Bradford gas water heater ,when I moved it back i get a howling sound.Removing the pilot window plate stops the noise but what could be causing it?

Comment: What else did you do?

Comment: Sounds like intake air noise. What's the situation there? Help us help you.

Comment: I removed the heat diffuser because of vibration,I got that to stop but then the whistling-howling started